# trying to set my background to change depending on the time

Tags: javascript, html

heres my code

```html
<style>

    body,
    html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .bgimg {
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        color:  black;
        font: areial;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
</style>

<div class="bgimg">   
    <div style="background-image: url(noon.png) ;">
    <script>
        var img = "background-image: ";
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getHours();
        if (n > 20 || n < 6)
                img.backgroundImage= "url(midnight.png)";
        else if (n > 6 && n < 8)
            img.backgroundImage= "url(sunrise.png)";
        else if (n > 8 && n < 18)
            img.backgroundImage= "url(noon.png)";
        else (n > 18 && n < 20)
            img.backgroundImage= "url(sunset.png)";
    </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

the script above is supposed to get the time then display one of the backgrounds but i cant get it to set the background. i dont get any errors so idk what to do.

Comment: `var img = "background-image: ";` What do you think this code should do? Instead apply a class/id to the div you need to change background

Comment: You are trying to set `backgroundImage` of `img` but `img` is string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must need to add `width` and `height` for where you show img.

```js
var img = document.querySelector(".change-background");
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
console.log(n)
if (n > 20 || n < 6)
    img.style.backgroundImage= "url(midnight.png)";
else if (n > 6 && n < 8)
     img.style.backgroundImage= "url(sunrise.png)";
else if (n > 8 && n < 18)
     img.style.backgroundImage= "url(https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/word-link-serious-businessman-hands-600w-180015809.jpg)";
else if (n > 18 && n < 20)
     img.style.backgroundImage= "url(sunset.png)";

console.log(img.style.backgroundImage);
```

```css
body,
    html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
  
    .bgimg {
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        color:  black;
        font: areial;
        font-size: 25px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .change-background {
      width: inherit;
      height: inherit;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="bgimg">   
    <div class="change-background" style="background-image: url('sunrise.png');">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note**: must check your path of `noon.png` and others img also

Comment: code works ty =]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the `script` tag in the `div`. You can put it somewhere in the bottom of the body. You are also getting the `div` element incorrectly. The `img` variable is just a string.

You just need to get the `div` element and then set its background image:

```html
<div class="bgimg">
    <!-- give it a class !-->
    <div class="imgdiv" style="background-image: url('noon.png');">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var img = document.querySelector(".imgdiv");
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours();
    if (n > 20 || n < 6) {
        img.style.backgroundImage = "url('midnight.png')";
    } else if (n > 6 && n < 8) {
        img.style.backgroundImage = "url('sunrise.png')";
    } else if (n > 8 && n < 18) {
        img.style.backgroundImage = "url('noon.png')";
    } else if (n > 18 && n < 20) {
        img.style.backgroundImage = "url('sunset.png')";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i tried this but it still isnt working

Comment: do you have discord? if you do can you add me (subaka#2931) so you can help me